# R: plotly and shiny barplot

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm making a barplot with [plotly](https://plot.ly/) based on the [World Phones example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/telephones-by-region.html).

The sidebarPanel does not work, can you tell me why?

```
data <- data.frame(x=rep(c('A','B','C'), each = 1, times = 3),
                   y=runif(9, 5, 10),
                   group=rep(c('2011','2012','2013'), each = 1, times= 3))
```

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
# Define the overall UI
shinyUI(
# Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
fluidPage(    
# Give the page a title
titlePanel("Barchart"),
# Generate a row with a sidebar
sidebarLayout(      
# Define the sidebar with one input
sidebarPanel(
selectInput("letter", "Letter:", levels(data[,1])),
hr()),
# Create a spot for the barplot
mainPanel(
plotlyOutput("dataPlot")  
))))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
# Fill in the spot we created for a plot
output$dataPlot <- renderPlotly({
# Render a barplot
p <- plot_ly(data, x = input$letter, y=y, group=group,type = "bar")
p})
})
```

Comment: `input$letter` return to you `A` and you havent colunm `A` in your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant fully understan what you wnat to see

but for example  if you want to plot only one letter by years

1) You have bad `df` as example -- `A` exist only into 2011

2) I use `data <- data.frame(x=rep(c('A','B','C'), each = 1, times = 3),
                       y=runif(9, 5, 10),
                       group=rep(c('2011','2012','2013'), each = 3, times= 1))`

3) try  `p <- plot_ly(data[data$x==input$letter,], x=group, y=y,type = "bar")`

Dont forget declare `data` into `ui` and `server`

And work only in browser not into rstudion viewer ( for me)

Comment: With your 'df' and the modification from [Dinesh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3854751/dinesh) this works for me. But am I forgetting to declare 'data' into either 'iu' or 'server'?

Comment: is it question? i dont know where you create df .. but if you create it only in `ui`, app not work because you havent df into `server`(and in other way). if you want to use data ( from sql for example) better way to create`uioutput` and `rederUI` `selectInput("letter"` on server side

Answer (score 3):

Every thing given by Batanicheck is correct, but a little modification to the plot get your exact output.

Replace

```
> p <- plot_ly(data[data$x==input$letter,], x=group, y=y,type = "bar")
```

**WITH**

```
> p <- plot_ly(data[data$x==input$letter,], x=x, y=y, group=group,type = "bar")
```

For me it works in browser as well as Rstudio viewer...